# Performance degrades as multiple tabs are opened SignalR

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, signalr

I am creating chat application. Due to the browser limitation to open 5-6 concurrent tabs from one connection, I used sub domian concept to open multiple tabs.

But now I am facing problem that, when multiple tabs are opened, chat process slows down.

It works fine when 4-5 tabs are opened but if more than 5 tabs are opened, overall process slows down and sometimes messages are received by the receiver in different order as they were send.

When I start closing the tabs, then signalr issue starts behaving normally as it was earlier.

One more issues I faced related to performance is when I open tabs quickly one after the other then also performance degrades. It sends messages after a minute or sometimes it takes long time to send message.

Can anyone suggest me the solution to this performance issue of SignalR?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance

Comment: hi Code.. I have visited this link earlier but this dosen't help me .

Comment: Well no one can help you with out any code